# How to implement MongoDB in angular?

Tags: angular, mongodb, mongodb-query, angular7

I am using **Angular7** and I would like to install **MongoDB** to my Angular application. What is the most straight forward i.e. simplest way to do this?

Comment: Angular is front end framework, if you want use MongoDB place that on backend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular is front-end framework. You can implement it in any framework as mediator to connect database with MongoDB.

if you want use MongoDB place that on back-end.

Answer (score 2):

To implement MongoDB as your database for your app using Angular as front-end framework, you can use `express.js` and `mongoose` in a file called `server.js`, where you will start a server for your app.

Use mongoose to connect your app to the mongodb database i.e. `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myangularappdb', ...)` or MongoClient `const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;`. You can choose to run your MongoDB locally or you can use mLab `mlab.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Angular is a Frond End UI Framework. If you are willing to Use MongoDB as your database, standard way is to create a backend APP with rest APIs connecting to your MongoDB.

1) Install and set up MangoDB database.
2) Node supports MongoDB with a Object Modelling called Mangoose, you can add that package as a dependency in your back end app.
3) Write rest APIs covering your logic to do operations on MangoDB. Use Express JS which has predefined way of writing APIs in node JS with minimal coding.
4) Connect to those APIs from your Angular UI app.

You can also have all these Angular, APIs created in the same app it might be difficult to maintain if the application features increases.

Comment: Okay, I think in angular7 have Express framework so that we can easily use as the backend.

Comment: Probably you are referring to something else, Angular7 doesn't have ExpressJS inbuilt in to it, we might have to add it as dependency. What i mean is explained in the link below, standard full stack application using MEAN (MongoDB, ExpressJS, Angular, Node) stack https://appdividend.com/2018/11/04/angular-7-crud-example-mean-stack-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Angular is client side framework that mean it 's not possible to have some back-end cipapility like connect to mongdb server .

simple you can implement express app and connet to mongdb and create an api to interact with tha back-end via http protocal

Answer (score 1):

Angular is a **Front-End** Framework. You can connect Mongo DB with a backend Framework like Java, Dotnet, nodejs etc,

You can then communicate with them via APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Mongo DB to be very specific is document-oriented database. and can be used with technologies that deals with backend stuff.If you are using front end framework like angular then you can use node js and expressjs or any other framework or technologies that is compatible with mongo db